# Prevent extra text from showing in input when it reaches the min and max values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input[type='number']` that validates on text change. The validation works just fine, however I'm very annoyed of the extra text appearing and disappearing.

Ex.
I already reached 10, then I will add 1 and it will become 101 then it changes to 10.

What I want is to fix it to 10 when the user inputs a number greater than it. Please see the fiddle.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7s6dk0z/)

Answer (score 0):

Write a  keypress function and if the value in the text box is greater than 10 return false/cancel the event